# Contractibility of regular CW sphere minus open star

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cw-complexes

Let $S$ be any regular CW decomposition of (a space homeomorphic to) the $n$-sphere, and consider a cell $\sigma$ of dimension $d \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$. Let $S'$ be the regular CW complex which remains after the open star of $\sigma$ is removed (that is, we remove **the interior** of $\sigma$ along with interiors of all cells $\tau$, if any, which contain the closure of $\sigma$ in their boundary).

I'd like to be able to make the following claim as a small part of a proof I'm writing:

> $S'$ is contractible.

Is this true? It certainly seems reasonable, and I could see a straightforward proof in the case where $S$ is a finite triangulation. If $S$ has only finitely many cells to begin with, I could obtain a triangulation by barycentric subdivision and then the desired statement holds. I'd really like to avoid that, but I worry about pathological examples like the Alexander horned sphere, etc.

So if I can't make the claim above, are there reasonable hypotheses to impose on $S$ (like: only finitely many cells allowed) which will make my desired claim true?

**Edit** of course there are only finitely many cells, see Mincong Zeng's comment. But do we need anything stronger in case the claim doesn't hold as-is?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, by Prop 1 in appendix A of Hatcher, a CW complex is compact if and only if it has finitely many cells.

Comment: Do you know a counterexample if you drop the assumption of regularity? (to save people time: a regular CW complex is one in which all attaching maps are homeomorphisms onto their images)

Comment: @JohnPardon: Start with a square, identify the left and right edges to a single edge $\sigma$ so you have a tube, then attach disks as top and bottom caps to make the boundary of a cylinder (homeomorphic to $S^2$). The open star of $\sigma$ is the complement of the disjoint top and bottom disks.

Comment: @TylerLawson Or you could use the minimal CW circle that glues the boundary of an interval to a single vertex. Then the open star of that vertex is everything and its complement is therefore empty.

Comment: @ViditNanda Great, that's much simpler.